# Distribution of Drupal aimed at the development of projects

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system, drupal-modules

Is there a distribution of Drupal or module aimed at the creation and development of projects in a collaborative way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common distributions are available at https://www.drupal.org/project/project_distribution.

I've used OpenAtrium which has some functionality on install but requires a little bit of setup. I'm getting ready to look at OpenLucius as a PM platform in my new position, but I haven't had a chance to set it up yet.